# Inconveniences with @HtmlHelper into monodevelop

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I'm newbie developing in monodevelop (linux). I'm creating a MVC 5 project and Web.config into views folder has:

```html
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

However in my Index.cshtml @Html.ActionLink("NHibernate", "Index") or whatever combination (like @Html.ActionLink("NHibernate", "Index", "Home", new { area = "NH" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })) is throwing following exception:

System.MissingMethodException
Method 'RouteCollection.get_AppendTrailingSlash' not found.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.Mvc.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.GetVirtualPathForArea (System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes, System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.String name, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary values, System.Boolean& usingAreas) [0x00052] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.GetVirtualPathForArea (System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes, System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.String name, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary values) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl (System.String routeName, System.String actionName, System.String controllerName, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues, System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routeCollection, System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues) [0x00035] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl (System.String routeName, System.String actionName, System.String controllerName, System.String protocol, System.String hostName, System.String fragment, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues, System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routeCollection, System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GenerateLinkInternal (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routeCollection, System.String linkText, System.String routeName, System.String actionName, System.String controllerName, System.String protocol, System.String hostName, System.String fragment, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GenerateLink (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routeCollection, System.String linkText, System.String routeName, System.String actionName, System.String controllerName, System.String protocol, System.String hostName, System.String fragment, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GenerateLink (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routeCollection, System.String linkText, System.String routeName, System.String actionName, System.String controllerName, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink (System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, System.String linkText, System.String actionName, System.String controllerName, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) [0x00029] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink (System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, System.String linkText, System.String actionName) [0x0000e] in :0 
  at ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute () [0x0010e] in /home/admin1/Proyectos/TestMVC/TestMVC/Views/Home/Index.cshtml:14 
  at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy () [0x00054] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy () [0x0001d] in :0 
  at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage () [0x0000d] in :0 
  at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy () [0x0001a] in :0 
  at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy (System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext pageContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer, System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase startPage) [0x00027] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer, System.Object instance) [0x000c7] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer) [0x00067] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) [0x00080] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0000b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0004f] in :0

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: What I'm doing wrong or what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Actual framework version in Monodevelop doesn't support AppendTrailingSlash property. Best solution for now is to use estandar html .